# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python

Estou fazendo uma tabela com nome, nota e situaçao de cada aluno

```
import pandas as pd

lista_nome = list()
lista_nota = list()
index = list()

while True:
    print("=" * 10)
    nomes = str(input(f"Nome: ")).capitalize()
    lista_nome.append(nomes)

    notas = float(input("Nota do aluno: "))
    lista_nota.append(notas)

    opcao = str(input("Deseja continuar? [S/N]: ")).upper()[0]
    print("=" * 10)

    for index in enumerate(lista_nota): 
        if index > 7:
            n1 = "APROVADO"
        else:
            n1 = "REPROVADO"

    if opcao == 'N':
        break

matriz = {"Nomes": lista_nome, "Nota": lista_nota, "Situação": n1}
x = pd.DataFrame(matriz)
print(x)
```

Quando eu rodo aparece isso:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

[Segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), `enumerate` retorna uma sequência de [**tuplas**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-tuple) contendo o índice e o respectivo elemento. Então no `for index in enumerate(lista_nota)` a variável `index` é uma tupla, e por isso dá esse erro ao tentar usá-la em uma comparação (`if index > 7`).
Mas no caso você parece querer verificar apenas o valor, então não precisaria de `enumerate`.

Outro detalhe é que você só deveria verificar as notas **depois** que todas fossem digitadas (ou seja, fora do `while`). Por fim, [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input(...))` é redundante e desnecessário.

E como você está usando o [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), pode criar a coluna "Situação" usando [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply):

```
import pandas as pd

nomes = []
notas = []

while True:
    print("=" * 10)
    nomes.append(input(f"Nome: ").capitalize())
    notas.append(float(input("Nota do aluno: ")))

    print("=" * 10)
    if input("Deseja continuar? [S/N]: ").upper()[0] == 'N':
        break

df = pd.DataFrame({ "Nomes": nomes, "Nota": notas })
df['Situação'] = df.apply(lambda row: "APROVADO" if row['Nota'] > 7 else "REPROVADO", axis=1)
print(df)
```

Também mudei os nomes de algumas variáveis. As listas de nomes e notas chamei respectivamente de `nomes` e `notas`, para dar a ideia de que elas podem ter mais de um nome e mais de uma nota (você estava usando esses nomes para as variáveis que só recebem um nome e uma nota, e veja que eliminei elas, já que não me pareceram necessárias, pois elas só servem para guardar o resultado do `input` que em seguida é adicionado na lista, então fiz tudo em um passo só).

Depois do `while` eu verifico a situação de cada nota, usando `apply` para criar a coluna "Situação", cujos valores são baseados na nota.

---

Mas se fosse para usar o `for` na lista de notas, uma alternativa é criar outra lista com as situações, assim:

```
nomes = []
notas = []
while True:
    print("=" * 10)
    nomes.append(input(f"Nome: ").capitalize())
    notas.append(float(input("Nota do aluno: ")))

    print("=" * 10)
    if input("Deseja continuar? [S/N]: ").upper()[0] == 'N':
        break

situacoes = []
for nota in notas:
    situacoes.append("APROVADO" if nota > 7 else "REPROVADO")

df = pd.DataFrame({ "Nomes": nomes, "Nota": notas, "Situação": situacoes })
print(df)
```

Ou, se quiser pode trocar as linhas do `for` por uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions):

```
situacoes = [ "APROVADO" if nota > 7 else "REPROVADO" for nota in notas ]
```